# "RNRangeSlider" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, rangeslider

I'm a little new to react-native and am trying to implement a basic range slider in my app. I'm using the range slider from @jesster2k10/react-native-range-slider (https://github.com/jesster2k10/react-native-range-slider) and followed the example exactly. i.e. I installed with

```
npm install --save @jesster2k10/react-native-range-slider
```

and

```
cd ios && pod install
```

I'm using a bare workflow and I'm starting with implementing it in ios only for now.

The error I'm getting is: **Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNRangeSlider" was not found in the UIManager.**

I've tried linking it with react-native link  but that doesn't work either.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This normally happens when the app needs to be rebuilt. Try closing your app and rebuilding it again.